# Convert Image and Sound Files to XNB files

Tags: c#, xna

I created a XNA Game Library Project that loads several sound and image files. But for the project to run, I need to convert these to XNB files. I am wondering, how do you go about doing that? Thanks!

Comment: Have you added these files to the Content project?

Comment: Hi, yea I've added these files to the ProjectContent folder. I also clicked on the .resx file and added the files there.

Comment: Then, Justin's answer will do it all for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [XNA Content Pipeline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203887.aspx) takes care of much of that for you.  If you are using the XNA Game Studio, importing many types of content files will automatically hook up the right pipeline (which you can then edit).